# Kubuntu doesn't load after ''Reached target multi-user.target - Multi User System.''

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

I've been trying everything I could find on the Internet, but as a Linux begginer i wasn't able to solve this isue. Basically the boot doesn't continue after it reaches multi-user.target, I have done fsck and found no problems, and I can aces the computer via the recovery mode in a streched monitor.

I can provide any further detail that might've help pointing out the issue.

Comment: Do your logs contain any relevant error or clues?

Comment: @user535733 After 12 hours of blood, sweat, and many expletives I was able to solve the issue. Now I find myself that the screen resolution is stuck at 4/3, yet I managed to boot to my normal Multi User system.

Comment: can you make answer about how you solved this problem please